# Нечеткий поиск подстроки в строке

Tags: java, поиск, нечеткий-поиск

Здравствуйте. Необходимо реализовать на Java поиск подстроки в строке.
Т.е. строка 
**"Разница между родившимися и умершими"** должна быть найдена в строке **"Разность между числом родившихся и числом умерших за определенное время (например, за один год) называют естественным приростом населения."**

А строка **"Ивановыми"** должна быть найдена в строке **"Иванов - древнейший житель города"**

Необходим лишь ответ - есть ли что-то похожее в строке. Посоветуйте что-нибудь, желательно уже реализованное на Java.

Comment: разбиение на слова + левенштейн

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Грубо говоря это делается в 3 шага:

1. Разбиваем строку на лексемы/слова
2. Полученные лексемы прогоняем через [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) c [русской морфологией](https://github.com/akuznetsov/russianmorphology) - в итоге получаем список лексем очищенный от падежных/родовых и прочих морфологичечких признаков характерных для великого могучего, то есть вместо:

> Разность между числом родившихся и числом умерших за определенное время

получим

> Разница между число родить и число умереть за определенный время

3. Далее для этих лексем вычисляем хэш функцию умеющую выдавать близкие значения хэша для похожих слов - например [SimHash](https://github.com/search?l=Java&q=simhash&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93) или что-то вроде упомянутого [Левенштейна](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0)

Остальное надеюсь объяснять не надо.